# JSON Slurper Offsets

Tags: json, groovy

I have a large JSON file that I'm trying to parse with JSON Slurper.  The JSON file consists of information about bugs so it has things like issue keys, descriptions, and comments.  Not every issue has a comment though.  For example, here is a sample of what the JSON input looks like:

```
    {
   "projects": [
      {
      "name": "Test Project",
      "key": "TEST",
      "issues": [
      {
         "key": "BUG-1",
         "priority": "Major",
         "comments": [
           {
             "author": "a1",
             "created": "d1",
             "body": "comment 1"
           },
           {
             "author": "a2",
             "created": "d2",
             "body": "comment 2"
           }
         ]
      },
      {
         "key": "BUG-2",
         "priority": "Major"
      },
      {
         "key": "BUG-3",
         "priority": "Major",
         "comments": [
           {
             "author": "a3",
             "created": "d3",
             "body": "comment 3"
           }
         ]
      }
    ]
}
]
}
```

I have a method that creates Issue objects based on the JSON parse.  Everything works well when every issue has at least one comment, but, once an issue comes up that has no comments, the rest of the issues get the wrong comments.  I am currently looping through the JSON file based on the total number of issues and then looking for comments using how far along in the number of issues I've gotten.  So, for example,

```
parsedData.issues.comments.body[0][0][0]
```

returns "comment 1".  However,

```
parsedData.issues.comments.body[0][1][0]
```

returns "comment 3", which is incorrect.  Is there a way I can see if a particular issue has any comments?  I'd rather not have to edit the JSON file to add empty comment fields, but would that even help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
parsedData.issues.comments.collect { it?.body ?: [] }
```

So it checks for a `body` and if none exists, returns an empty list

**UPDATE**
Based on the update to the question, you can do:

```
parsedData.projects.collectMany { it.issues.comments.collect { it?.body ?: [] } }
```

Comment: Thanks!  But where does the index information go in that?  How do we know which issue it is looking at?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... The first list will contain the first comments, the second the second, etc

Comment: I see what you mean now.  I'm getting a NullPointerException though.  It says, "Cannot get property 'comments' on null object".

Comment: Can you give a brief valid anonymised example of some json that gives the error?

Comment: Sure, I edited the sample above so that it is now my exact test JSON text.

Comment: @user2221518 See updated answer for the JSON mentioned in question.